# Using diy lm386 preamp on standard commercial amp?

Tags: audio, mixer, power-amplifier, preamp, lm386

I have a small intercom-like device that has been siting around.
It looks something like [this](https://www.smgeurope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/f537e62d2055f783a4002df5400b0ca8/3/3/330-hm222.jpg).
I suppose that inside is just a basic elect-mic and a button.
Also i have an power amp which i used to play music at occasions. [Amp model](http://www.inter-m.net/en/view/productView.asp?seq=151).
So now i'm wondering can i make an basic lm386 mic preamp which will operate at 12v and plug it in amps input? or i have to make maybe some sort of passive mic pre-amp if there is such a thing?

I hope i did not confuse you with my explanation since im very good at doing that.

P.S.
I need to have separate preamp for my intercom device since im also making passive audio mixer which will use audio from pc and audio from this mic which will then go into one channel in my power amp.

Also here is my very poor done schematics of my idea:
[image]

Comment: LM386 is not an opamp or a preamp, so while it'll work after a fashion it won't be a very good solution.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions for a good idea? :)